# Tkinter doesn't find my picture in my program

Tags: python, tkinter, canvas

I am trying to create an image in the tkinter window but I cannot.
I think tkinter can't find my picture in my file.
I try change the dimensions but I cannot and I try change a name of the picture but  it does not change anything.
This is my code:

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import messagebox
import re, game

money = 0

def espace_def(nombre):
    for i in range(nombre):
        espace = Label(frame_left, text="", fg="#444444", bg="#444444", font=("Courrier", 50))
        espace.pack()

def exit():
    window.destroy()

def launch():
    if (re.fullmatch(r'\b([A-Za-z]{3,})\b', entry_name.get())):
        exit()
        game.run()
    else:
        messagebox.showerror(title="Erreur", message="Vous pseudo est invalide !")

window = Tk()
window.title("Ghost game")
window.config(bg="#333333")
window.iconbitmap("assets\icon.ico")
window.attributes('-fullscreen', True)
frame_right = Frame(window, bg="#444444")
frame_right.pack(side=RIGHT)
frame_left = Frame(window, bg="#444444")
frame_left.pack(side=LEFT)
frame = Frame(window, bg="#333333")
frame.pack(expand=YES)
title_name = Label(frame_left, text="Entrez votre pseudo :", fg="#C728D9", bg="#444444", font=("Courrier", 30))
title_name.pack(pady=10, padx=10)
entry_name = Entry(frame_left, fg="#C728D9", bg="#555555", font=("Courrier", 25))
entry_name.pack(pady=10, fill=X, padx=10)
espace_def(1)
money_text1 = Label(frame_left, text="Money :", fg="#C728D9", bg="#444444", font=("Courrier", 30))
money_text1.pack(pady=10, padx=10)
money_text2 = Label(frame_left, text=str(money)+"$", fg="#C728D9", bg="#444444", font=("Courrier", 30))
money_text2.pack(pady=10, padx=10)
espace_def(4)
exit_button = Button(frame_left, text="Fermer", fg="#000000", bg="#C728D9", font=("Courrier", 30), command=exit)
exit_button.pack(pady=10, padx=10)
espace_def(1)
image = PhotoImage(file="assets/bg.png")
canvas = Canvas(frame, width=450, height=233, bg='#444444', bd=0, highlightthickness=0)
canvas.create_image(450, 233, image=image)
canvas.pack()
play_button = Button(frame, text="Lance", fg="#000000", bg="#C728D9", font=("Courrier", 30), command=launch)
play_button.pack(pady=10, padx=10)
window.mainloop()
```

Comment: you understand that you are putting an image right outside the canvas? you have set its x and y coordinates to the width and height of the canvas so obviously the image won't be seen in the canvas, try changing coordinates to 0, 0: `canvas.create_image(0, 0, image=image)` (or technically could use `canvas.create_image(450, 233, image=image, anchor='se')`), also use some blank lines to separate your code into logical blocks, otherwise it is very hard to read it or understand anything, also don't use `*` when importing